# How to get bundles and jars depended by Eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox, tycho

I am using maven to build my Eclipse RCP applications. I got confused by how to resolve dependencies. I read the documentation of Tycho. It just explain how to build but no much about how to resolve dependencies. How to use maven download bundles to my target platform folder? And how to import ordinary jar packages such as thumbnailator which is not packaged to OSGi bundle? I added dependency in pom.xml, but can not import package in my MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you use in a RCP must be in packaged in a plugin.

You may have to write a simple plug-in to include any jars you have which are not plug-ins.